# "from albumentations.augmentations.transforms import Crop" showing error "Cannot import Crop"

Tags: python, albumentations

I am trying to import python package, but having import errors

`from albumentations.augmentations.transforms import Crop`

showing error

`cannot import name 'Crop'`

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with resize.
Try this ([source](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/issues/564)):

1. Update albumentations: `pip install --upgrade albumentations`
2. Also you can install latest version from git: `pip install git+https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations.git`

But it didn't help me =( I used next:

```
import albumentations as A
resized_image = A.Resize( height, weight)(image=image) ['image']
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
from albumentations.augmentations.crops.functional import crop
```

Answer (score 0):

From version 1.0.0 onwards of the library the `Crop` transform is moved to `albumentations.augmentations.crops.transforms` so you need to update your import to the following:

```py
from albumentations.augmentations.crops.transforms import Crop
```